# nutch does not crawl sites that allows all crawler by robots.txt

Tags: server, web-crawler, firewall, nutch

I collect more than 300 urls on seed.txt that should be crawled by nutch, but approximately 80 nutch did not crawl. I controlled these sites and find out that most of these sites has allowed to crawl in robots.txt by:

User-agent: *

Why nutch doesn't crawl these sites? Is there a possibility to fix this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The statement `User-agent: *` just defines the scope of the following rules: `Disallow: /` forbids crawling, it's generally allowed by `Allow: /` but often there is a combination of path-specific rules. Could you share examples which hosts are not crawled? Also recommended for a quick check: `bin/nutch parsechecker -checkRobotsTxt https://example.com/` (replace the URL).

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian, for your reply. The following hosts not crawled: dolap.com, aysira.com, pronovias.com and papillone.com. I will try the quick check you described, and looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks!

Comment: Running `bin/nutch parsechecker -checkRobotsTxt https://dolap.com/` does not show any issue: the homepage is fetched, links are extracted. What's in the crawl logs? What's the fetch status? Any custom configurations (URL filters) which could be the reason?

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault, dolap.com has been crawled, dugun-mugun.com has not and it has no restriction in robots.txt for nutch crawler or my http.user.agent.

Comment: Running `bin/nutch parsechecker -followRedirects -checkRobotsTxt https://dugun-mugun.com/` is successful. But note the `-followRedirects`! Nutch follows redirects by default in the next cycle. Consequently, you need to run the crawler over multiple cycles/rounds (aka. "depth") or adjust the configuration property [http.redirect.max](https://nutch.apache.org/apidocs/apidocs-1.18/resources/nutch-default.xml#http.redirect.max). Of course, also the URL filters must accept the redirect targets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me very much. Now I know what I have to care about in the configuration.